# GWT ListBox Styling

Tags: css, gwt, listbox

I wish to change the way ListBox looks using CSS

- Change the border color - Tried using the usual border-color:red. Worked on Firefox. No effect on IE Still the standard blue color
- Change the Color of the arop down arrow. No idea how to go about doing it.

Any idea how do i do this

Thanks
J

Comment: Have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403861/how-to-change-my-gwt-listbox-style/15359987#15359987

That will get you started.  You go through the different elements and change the style of each one appropriately. Also you can introduce a CSS class if you want and setStyleName with you like.. but once you have the Element you can do what you want... I think that is the best approach...

Hit like.. need a few..

Answer (score 0):

Check the rendered html in firebug and add appropriate css in the index.html (or the page where you are including the gwt module). In the GWT code add the css class in the listbox by using

```
listBox.setStyleName("the classes defined in the css for list box")
```