# how to change my GWT listbox style

Tags: css, gwt

How can i change the style of my GWT default list box .
in a way that every list box in my application will change .

Shouldn't this work ?

```
 .gwt-ListBox{
color: red !important;
```

}

thanks.

Comment: used to this...............  body .gw-ListBox{color:red !important}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..................................................

Hi now do this over write

```
   body .gwt-ListBox{
color: green !important;

}


.gwt-ListBox{
color: red !important;

}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/cqbawPGP)***

---

***Second is***

Define your `body id`

as like this

**html**

```
<body id="someid">
<div class="gwt-ListBox">
some text
</div>

</body>
```

**Css**

```
#someid .gwt-ListBox{
color:green !important;
}
```

Comment: There is only one body element, why add an id to it?  There is no need to use <body> at all - you can style <select> directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this programatically, then here is how I achieved it..

In this particular snippet of code, I've set the background colour of one 
particular item (the one named ABC) in the list box to red.

But you get the idea, you can do as you like once you have the option element.

--- Create and populate the list box

> ```
> ListBox listBox;
> listBox.addItem("123");
> listBox.addItem("ABC");
> ```

-- here is how to set a particular item's style...

> ```
> NodeList<Node> children = listBox.getElement().getChildNodes();       
>     for (int i = 0; i< children.getLength();i++) {
>       Node child = children.getItem(i);
>         if (child.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
>           if (child instanceof OptionElement) {
>             OptionElement optionElement = (OptionElement) child;
>               if (optionElement.getValue().equals("ABC")) {
>                  optionElement.getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");  
>               }                   
>             }
>           }           
>        }
> ```

Hit like if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS file, if you want to change ALL lists, as you stated in your question:

```
select {
    color: red !important;
}
```