# GWT : label to the Listbox

Tags: gwt

I have a listbox in GWT. there are various items in the dropdown.
i want to set a label to the listbox. and move it to the right direction.
Can anybody please help.

```
private ListBox makeCalculationMethodField(List<String> cList) {
    ListBox dropBox = new ListBox();
    dropBox.setVisibleItemCount(0);
     for (String name : cList) {
         dropBox.addItem(name);
          }
    return dropBox;
}
```

How do i add label to this listbox.
If I am using the below code.the alignment is not right.

```
Label label =new Label();
label.setTitle("Calculation MethodNames:");
label.setStyleName("arial");
formPanel.add(label);
```

Comment: Have you tried [Label.setAutoHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignmentConstant.ALIGN_RIGHT )](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LabelBase.html#setAutoHorizontalAlignment(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment.AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant))?

Comment: you can add your own custom style directly on listbox itself. for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403861/how-to-change-my-gwt-listbox-style) or you can override existing one.

Comment: Finally it worked when I used SimpleComboBox. thanks